# Electron "ready-to-show" event not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, electron, electron-forge

Here is a block of code from my application [Codey](https://github.com/Liamohara/Codey).

***src/main.py***

```
// Show window once it has finished initialising
docsWindow.once("ready-to-show", () => {
  if (darkMode) {
    docsWindow.webContents.send("dark-mode:toggle");
  }

  if (!isDarwin) {
    docsWindow.webContents.send("platform:not-darwin");
  }

  docsWindow.webContents.send("docs:jump", section);

  docsWindow.show();
});
```

***src/docs/renderer.js***

```
window.api.darkMode.toggle.receive(toggleDarkMode);
```

When darkMode = true, toggleDarkMode is never run.

My application has two different windows - an editor and a docs window. For both windows, on the "ready-to-show" event, "dark-mode:toggle" is sent to the renderer process. However, the docs window fails to run the toggleDarkMode function whilst it works for the editor window.

**Note:** The application must be packaged using "yarn package" as some features do not work in the dev environment.

Any help will be much appreciated.

(Repo: https://github.com/Liamohara/Codey)

Comment: It may be an initialisation or scoping problem. Is `darkMode` set prior to the `docsWindow` `ready-to-show` event being fired. Else, what scope is `darkMode` set in? It may be out of scope for the `docsWindow.once("ready-to-show", () => {...})` function. A little more code may help...

Comment: If I remove the condition, the result is still the same. The rest of the code is on my github repo: https://github.com/Liamohara/Codey. Thanks

Comment: Needing to refer to external sources to view code is discouraged as it makes it difficult for people to quickly and easily answer your question. Not many people on SO will go that far to answer a question.

Comment: Within your `src/docs/renderer.js` file, the line of code `window.api.darkMode.toggle.recieve(toggleDarkMode)` is missing it's listener argument. Ref: [ipcRenderer.on(channel, listener)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendereronchannel-listener)

Comment: That's because it's defined in the preload.js. Since, electron 5.0, contextIsolation is true by default. Ref: [Planned Breaking API Changes (5.0)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/breaking-changes#planned-breaking-api-changes-50)

Comment: The API function does work (as shown when the app's dark-mode button is pressed) but not on the "ready-to-show" event. Unfortunately, as there is a fair chunk of code, it's difficult to display all the related parts in a single SO question. In a nutshell, the peculiarity I am experiencing is how the "ready-to-show" event works as expected for the editor window but unfortunately not for the docs window.

Comment: Could it be because `recieve` is spelt wrong? The correct spelling is `receive`.

Comment: Nice spot. However, it's user-defined so the bug remains after changing it. The source code has been changed to use the accurate spelling.

Comment: What's with [line 14]( https://github.com/Liamohara/Codey/blob/058fb0c2c40ee453b51f2191461a1b95c75a42e5/src/docs/renderer.js#L14) in your [`src/docs/renderer.js`](https://github.com/Liamohara/Codey/blob/master/src/docs/renderer.js) file? Do you receieve any console errors regarding this?

Comment: I forgot to remove it and it makes no difference. I have now found the solution. For anyone that's interested, I am going to post an explanation today. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that's interested. I found a solution to my issue.

***src/main.py***

```
     // Show window once it has finished initialising
-    docsWindow.once("ready-to-show", () => {
+    docsWindow.webContents.once("did-finish-load", () => {
       if (darkMode) {
         docsWindow.webContents.send("dark-mode:toggle");
       }
    
       if (!isDarwin) {
         docsWindow.webContents.send("platform:not-darwin");
       }
    
       docsWindow.webContents.send("docs:jump", section);
    
       docsWindow.show();
     });
```

In the docs window, there is more HTML content to be renderered than in the editor window. As a result, the DOM takes longer to load and the "ready-to-show" event is emitted before it has finished. Using the "did-finish-load" event, ensures that the API functions are not called before the DOM has finished loading.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was the `docsWindow.webContents.send()` function. It is a blind and.
deceptive bug.

```
    // Show window once it has finished initialising
      docsWindow.once("ready-to-show", () => {if (darkMode) {
    docsWindow.webContents.send("dark-mode:toggle");
  }

  if (!isDarwin) {
    docsWindow.webContents.send("platform:not-darwin");
  }

  docsWindow.webContents.send("docs:jump", section);

  docsWindow.show();
});
```

When the window is ready to show, it is created, but the `HTML and renderer process` aren't loaded yet, there'simply no handler registered yet. The preload script gets the data/message but doesn't know what to do with it. By the time the listener is registered, the main process already marked that done, and proceeded to others lines of code.

> Sometimes, it works because the renderer process runs before the main process sends the message and registers the listener.

> If you send the message to the window as soon as it's created it has no time to load the page and load the js to recieve the message.

The solution is to wrap it in the 'did-finish-load' event so it waits for the page to be ready before sending the message, like you did it.

```
    / Show window once it has finished initialising
-    docsWindow.once("ready-to-show", () => {
+    docsWindow.webContents.once("did-finish-load", () => {
       if (darkMode) {
         docsWindow.webContents.send("dark-mode:toggle");
       }
    
       if (!isDarwin) {
         docsWindow.webContents.send("platform:not-darwin");
       }
    
       docsWindow.webContents.send("docs:jump", section);
    
       docsWindow.show();
     });
```

A second approach is to initially set `BrowserWindow.options.show` to `false` and only call `win.show()` after sending the channel/message

```
const win=new BrowserWindow({
   //width,
   //height,
   show: false
})
```

```
    win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    win.webContents.send("test", "test value")
    win.show();
});
```

A third approach is to set a `setTimeout`function to send the
channel/message after being sure the `renderer process` has registered the listener

```
setTimeout(function() {
      win.webContents.send("channel", "test value")
     }, 1500);
```

Another option is to use the other ways of inter process communication pr0vided by electron (well documented in the link below)
The `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer` models

> https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc